# Why does [google-buzz] have a tag wiki?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I noticed that [Bob Aman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90723/bob-aman) managed to get the tag editor badge for the [google-buzz] badge. If you look at the [stats page for this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-buzz/stats), it indicate that there are only 17 question with tag, and none of the answerers are even close to the 100 points needed to create/edit that wiki. So the obvious question is:

**How did he create the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-buzz/info)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tag wikis can be edited by users with more than 2000 reputation, provided:
>
> - They are in the top 20 answerers for this tag or
> - They have a total score of 100 or more for this tag

So as Bob has more than 2000 reputation and is probably in the top 20 answerers for the tag he'll be allowed to edit it.

**UPDATE**

The rules have now been changed. Anyone can propose a tag wiki edit and 5K users can [approve them](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). 20K users can now [edit any tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki)

Comment: *Stare at quote for a second* Wait what **OR**!? I thought it was **AND**... (blushes)

Comment: I'd always thought both was required because if it was either we could just go and create tag-wikis on some obscure tags... hang on... hmmm.... we *could*, couldn't we? *Evil laugh*

Comment: @YiJiang, in your defense, there _is_ an "and" in there: (2000 total rep) & ((top20answerersInTag) | (scoreInTag >= 100))

Comment: Note that, while this answer remains correct, the rules for editing tag wikis have changed. Now, any user with 20,000 rep may edit any tag wiki.

Comment: @Popular - thanks. That's the 2nd answer I've had to update today!

Comment: @Chris, well, maybe you should stop writing answers about things that will change in the future.

Comment: @Pop - if I could do that it would make my work that much easier too!