# Question mark is treated as independent word in the StackExchance Inbox

Tags: support, global-inbox

One picture > 1000 words:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

I expect the question mark to stick to the "span" word and if not enough space, both of them should be wrapped down together.

Ordinary HTML wrap is working this way, [just made sure of this](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/7T6em/) now. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088998/how-do-i-align-these-3-divs-and-a-span) title had a space before the question mark, so it's treated as a separate word by the browser. Simples ;).

Comment: [We've all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62613/reputation-for-unregistered-account/62619#62619) [been there before ;)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63203/why-does-google-buzz-have-a-tag-wiki) - just remember, your erm... stupidity is helping someone on Meta get free Meta reps :P